# how to call data from DB to a language file then call it to the blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i'm trying to call the data i need to the lang files then call it back in the blade file using the {{trans('')}}

tried to add the path into the lang file and call it back but it wont work

this is the lang file

```
'menu_1'=> '$category[\'languages\'][0][\'title\']',
'menu_2'=> '{{$category[\'languages\'][1][\'title\']}}'
```

and this is the blade file

```
 {{trans('main.menu_1')}}
```

i need it to show the menu_1 name in the blade file but instead it's showing

```
$category[\'languages\'][0][\'title\']
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm the only one not understanding your intentions. But can you explain a bit what exactly your goal is? If I understood correctly, then my advice would be to not store PHP code in a database in order to evaluate it later because it is highly insecure.

Answer (score 0):

Your Translation Text ist a String and is not interpreted as PHP. A way to get your code working would be to use `{{array_get($category,trans('main.menu_1')}`} and store a the array path as dot notation in your language file like `'menu_1'=>'languages.0.title'`

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-get